Openapi type generation issue "fetch is not defined"
I using the openapi-typescript-codegen package to generate types from swagger endpoint of a spring boot backend. The command used to work fine before but after we updated stuff due to vulnerabilities checking. This command is not working. I don't know exactly when it stopped. I tried updating to the latest version but the error is the same. 
It looks like fetch is not installed. I tried installing it separately as well but a dependency is failing. What do I do here?
I expect types to be generated in the specified output folder like before but not getting "fetch is not defined" error.

Upgrading to the specific version of 0.13.0 fixed the issue.
npm i openapi-typescript-codegen@0.13.0 

